# Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()') and datetime in Mysql

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, datetime, zend-db-table

So I am having a strange problem on live website, and I am not sure what is causing the problem since in datetime field in mysql table sometimes time is mapped and more often it isn't. However date is always mapped.

Code goes like this:

```
   $party_system_id = $this->blabla->addUser($username, 'None', 'None', '',
   $email,$promo_code,$distributor_id);

    if ($party_system_id!=0){

    $loginToken = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));    

        $params = array(
            'sponsorId' => $sponsor_id,
            'refferalId' => $referral_id,
            'accountType' => $type,
            'email' => $email,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => md5($password),
            'firstName' => 'n/a',
            'lastName' => 'n/a',
            'expires' => $expiration_date,
            'activated' => 1,
            'gender' => $gender,
            'languageId' => 38,
            'onlineStatus'=> 0,
            'status' => 5,
            'dateAdded' => new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'),
            'blaId' => $party_system_id,
    'loginToken' => $token,
            'termsAccepted' => 1
        );

        return $this->insert($params);

    }
```

And registration is allways fine, but like I said for lot of users insted of:
**2012-05-16 10:20:33** I would get: **2012-05-16 00:00:00** and of-course it is not 00:00:00 at the moment of registration :)

I am not sure what can be a problem, mysql, script structure, or Zend_Db_Expr. I also don't have an idea how to properly debug this, but all suggestions are more then welcome :)

Comment: Your code looks fine. Do you have any edit screens which might be updating the row after creation?

Comment: NOW() should work in all cases - that's really strange.

Answer (score 1):

make sure dateAdded field does have Y-m-d H:i:s as a format,
but you can also simply use  `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

```
  $params = array(
        'sponsorId' => $sponsor_id,
        'refferalId' => $referral_id,
        'accountType' => $type,
        'email' => $email,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => md5($password),
        'firstName' => 'n/a',
        'lastName' => 'n/a',
        'expires' => $expiration_date,
        'activated' => 1,
        'gender' => $gender,
        'languageId' => 38,
        'onlineStatus'=> 0,
        'status' => 5,
        'dateAdded' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'blaId' => $party_system_id,
        'loginToken' => $token,
        'termsAccepted' => 1
    );
```

Comment: It works, on the same way, some members do have a time mapped but most of them don't is there any suggestion how to debug that ?